# Adding vector layer feature from REST API URL (HTTPS) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geojson, api, rest, http

I'm simply trying to import this feature directly into QGIS 3.16.3-Hannover as a new vector layer:

https://api3.geo.admin.ch/rest/services/api/MapServer/find?layer=ch.swisstopo.swissboundaries3d-land-flaeche.fill&searchText=ch&searchField=id&returnGeometry=true&geometryFormat=geojson

When loading it into a web browser, it shows the GeoJSON object as follows:

[image: geojson object]

Well, it's not *directly* a GeoJSON as it's "encapsulated" as the first (and only) element of the JSON array called `results`.
Which is probably the source of the following problem...

Because when trying to load it in QGIS*, I first get this message:

> Download with "Protocol" source type has failed, do you want to try the "File" source type?

and if I click "No", it then shows this error:

> Invalid Data Source: /vsicurl/https://api3.geo.admin.ch/rest/services/api/MapServer/find?layer=ch.swisstopo.swissboundaries3d-land-flaeche.fill&searchText=ch&searchField=id&returnGeometry=true&geometryFormat=geojson is not a valid or recognized data source.

How could I tell QGIS to first unpack the first element of the `results` array so that it can (hopefully) read the GeoJSON feature?

Changing the protocol type from HTTP/HTTPS/FTP to GeoJSON does help, but then the feature is not properly loaded on the table of content (it has no geometry):

[image: no geometry feature loaded]

*I'm trying to load it through the Data Source Manager > Vector > Source Type: "Protocol: HTTP(S), cloud, etc..." and by simply pasting the URL into, well, the URI field.

This is the API doc: https://api3.geo.admin.ch/services/sdiservices.html#find

Comment: Try with source type "File". See https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2021-September/049838.html. Proxy server may cause problems but that has not been  confirmed.

Comment: By using "File", I end up with the exact same result in the table of content that when I'm changing the HTTP protocol to GeoJSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like GeoJSON is a little confusing for QGIS.

Using "geometryFormat" rather than Type

> `https://api3.geo.admin.ch/rest/services/api/MapServer/ch.swisstopo.swissboundaries3d-land-flaeche.fill/CH?geometryFormat=geojson&sr=4326`

Is working for certain urls

Example:

[image]

Comment: Hmm, ok then, so it's the `/find` endpoint which seems to encapsulate the results in a so called `results` array here. Without that endpoint, it's indeed working well. I also fix my post, it was a typo from my side when writing `geometryType` as a parameter instead of `geometryFormat`.

Answer (score 3):

It may be convenient to use a VRT file if you often use the same remote layer in different QGIS projects instead of copying/pasting it in each of them.

Put in file `myvrt_demo.vrt` the following content and drag and drop the vrt file within QGIS

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="swissboundaries3d_land_flaeche_fill">
        <SrcDataSource>https://api3.geo.admin.ch/rest/services/api/MapServer/ch.swisstopo.swissboundaries3d-land-flaeche.fill/CH?geometryFormat=geojson&sr=4326</SrcDataSource>
        <SrcLayer>feature</SrcLayer>
        <LayerSRS>EPSG:4326</LayerSRS>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this very nice hint which will for sure be helpful for saving complex requests.

Answer (score 1):

QGIS may have some problem with connecting to services but in this case I fear that the result would be failure in any case. GDAL does not find geometry nor attributes from this JSON.

```
ogrinfo "https://api3.geo.admin.ch/rest/services/api/MapServer/find?layer=ch.swisstopo.swissboundaries3d-land-flaeche.fill&searchText=ch&searchField=id&returnGeometry=true&geometryType=geojson" -al
INFO: Open of `https://api3.geo.admin.ch/rest/services/api/MapServer/find?layer=ch.swisstopo.swissboundaries3d-land-flaeche.fill&searchText=ch&searchField=id&returnGeometry=true&geometryType=geojson'
      using driver `GeoJSONSeq' successful.

Layer name: GeoJSONSeq
Geometry: Unknown (any)
Feature Count: 1
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
```

Test in geojsonlint.com returns result "Invalid GeoJSON
Line 1: "type" member required".